# sum the value of gridview column on selection of checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a price column that show the total price of the checked rows. Originally I tried do this with the selection button but it didn't work, so, I added a checkbox into the gridview. now i need when i check some rows the sum of those rows come out on a label I tired this code but I get an error:

```
    double sum = 0;

    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
    {  
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("Checkbox1"); 
        if (cb.Checked)
        {
            double amount = Convert.ToDouble(gvr.Cells[2].Text);
            sum += amount;
        }


        Label1.Text = sum.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: please elaborate the error and tell us the exact error message you are getting? *i have error double sum = 0;* is not very clear

Comment: I guess he is getting the (Object reference is not set to an instance of an object) :)

Comment: sorry i didnt mention the error earlier its "Input string was not in a correct format"

Answer (score 0):

What i assumed that your are doing all this work outside of the grid, i mean you have a button some where on your page by clicking which you run this code. right??? if yes then you have to include one more thing in your code, and that is a check for datarow...

double sum = 0;

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
{  
 if(gvr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
 {
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("Checkbox1"); 
    if (cb.Checked)
    {
        //check wether the cell value is empty or not, if empty take a 0 instead...
        double amount = gvr.Cells[2].Text.Trim() != null && gvr.Cells[2].Text.Length>0 ? Convert.ToDouble(gvr.Cells[2].Text.Trim()) : 0;
        sum += amount;
    }


    Label1.Text = sum.ToString();
  }

}
```

if not is the situation, then you have to do it on the Change event of each checkbox..
inform me about the problem if solved, I'll be glade to help you...

Comment: yea i have a button outside the grid but when i tried ur code i get the same error which is "Input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: that is just becoz the value in the cell you are converting to double is empty. you have to check first wether the cell value can b converted to double??

Comment: why is it empty while it contains number u r rite i put a break and the text doesnt show anything but i dont get why

Comment: may be you are indexing your cell with wrong number. i.e cell index starts from 0..

Comment: oh my god i'm so stupid its not cell 2 its cell 1 but becoz i was tryin some stuff earlier and then shifted the numbers to cell 1 i didnt notice i feel so dumb anyways thank you so much and the first code worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

double sum = 0;

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
{  
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("Checkbox1"); 
    if (cb.Checked)
    {
        double amount = Convert.ToDouble(gvr.Cells[2].Text.replace("&nbsp",""));
        sum += amount;
    }


    Label1.Text = sum.ToString();

}
```

Comment: double amount = Convert.ToDouble(gvr.Cells[2].Text.Trim();